# При попытке парсить excel таблицу выводится ошибка

Tags: java, excel

```
public class Excel {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    FileInputStream s = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/_QWERTY_/Исходники/Dima/Try.xls");
    Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(s);
    String result = wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
    System.out.println(result);
    s.close();
}}
```

При попытке парсить excel таблицу на java выводится ошибка

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.math3.util.ArithmeticUtils
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 9 more
```

Comment: poi какой версии?

Comment: во-первых, покажите свои зависимости, во-вторых, покажите пример файла. ошибка говорит, что вам не хватает этой библиотеки https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3/3.6.1 , но я не знаю какая именно строка кода вызывает эту ошибку. если это ваш код с попыткой использовать эту утилиту, то достаточно подключить зависимость, если это POI, то вам не хватает зависимостей самого пакета POI